# "'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" in IntelliJ WebStorm

Tags: android, webstorm

I'm still getting this error after modifying PATH. How do I go about fixing this?

[image]
<sup>**'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file**</sup>  <sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: are you sure you set the PATH correctly?

Comment: Please post your code as text rather than a screenshot.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure to add the folder where `adb.exe` is located (usually `C:\Users\Your.Name\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools`, you can run `where adb` command in cmd console to find it) to `%PATH%` under 'system environment variables' and then restart WebStorm

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this is included in your path : `$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/` with `$ANDROID_HOME` being the root of your Android SDK directory